# How can I test whether an Azure Service exists or not, by name?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

For example, I will use this in PowerShell ISE (with admin privileges), [per the documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495193.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Test-AzureName –Service "MyNameService1"
```

**Expected result:**

This command tests to see if the "MyNameService1" is an existing Microsoft Azure cloud service name.

**Actual Result:**

```
Test-AzureName : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-AzureName –Service "MyNameService1"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Test-AzureName], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.CloudService.TestAzureNameCommand
```

I'm just not understanding what this is telling me, especially because I copy+paste the code from the documentation. Was I supposed to have something installed locally here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following PowerShell to check whether a Service exists in you cloud Environment.

```
Get-AzureRmResourceProvider
```

Note: You need to have Azure PowerShell 1.0.0 or greater.

Before you use this command, you need to log into your Azure Cloud.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

You will get output similar to this:

```
ProviderNamespace               RegistrationState ResourceTypes                                                                                          Locations
-----------------               ----------------- -------------                                                                                          ---------
Microsoft.AppService            Registered        {apiapps, appIdentities, gateways, deploymenttemplates...}                                             {East US, West US, South Central US, North Europe...}
Microsoft.Backup                Registered        {BackupVault}                                                                                          {West US, East US, North Europe, West Europe...}
Microsoft.Batch                 Registered        {batchAccounts, operations, locations, locations/quotas}                                               {West Europe, East US, East US 2, West US...}
Microsoft.ClassicCompute        Registered        {domainNames, checkDomainNameAvailability, domainNames/slots, domainNames/slots/roles...}              {East Asia, Southeast Asia, East US, East US 2...}
Microsoft.ClassicNetwork        Registered        {virtualNetworks, reservedIps, quotas, gatewaySupportedDevices...}                                     {East Asia, Southeast Asia, East US, East US 2...}
Microsoft.ClassicStorage        Registered        {storageAccounts, quotas, checkStorageAccountAvailability, storageAccounts/services...}                {East Asia, Southeast Asia, East US, East US 2...}
Microsoft.Compute               Registered        {availabilitySets, virtualMachines, virtualMachines/extensions, virtualMachines/diagnosticSettings...} {East US, East US 2, West US, Central US...}
microsoft.insights              Registered        {components, webtests, queries, alertrules...}                                                         {Central US, West US, East US, North Europe...}
Microsoft.MobileEngagement      Registered        {appcollections, appcollections/apps, checkappcollectionnameavailability, supportedplatforms}          {Central US, North Europe}
Microsoft.Network               Registered        {virtualNetworks, publicIPAddresses, networkInterfaces, loadBalancers...}                              {West US, East US, North Europe, West Europe...}
Microsoft.OperationalInsights   Registered        {workspaces, storageInsightConfigs, linkTargets, operations}                                           {East US, West Europe}
Microsoft.Scheduler             Registered        {jobcollections, operations}                                                                           {North Central US, South Central US, North Europe, West Europe...}
Microsoft.Sql                   Registered        {operations, locations, locations/capabilities, checkNameAvailability...}                              {West Europe, South Central US, East US 2, Central US...}
Microsoft.Storage               Registered        {storageAccounts, operations, usages, checkNameAvailability...}                                        {East US, East US 2, East US 2 (Stage), West US...}
Microsoft.Web                   Registered        {sites/extensions, sites/slots/extensions, sites/instances, sites/slots/instances...}                  {Brazil South, East Asia, East US, Japan East...}
Microsoft.ADHybridHealthService Registered        {services, addsservices, configuration, operations...}                                                 {West US}
Microsoft.Authorization         Registered        {roleAssignments, roleDefinitions, classicAdministrators, permissions...}                              {}
Microsoft.Features              Registered        {features, providers}                                                                                  {}
Microsoft.Resources             Registered        {subscriptions, subscriptions/providers, subscriptions/operationresults, resourceGroups...}            {Central US, East Asia, Southeast Asia, East US...}
microsoft.support               Registered        {operations, supporttickets}                                                                           {North Central US, South Central US, Central US, West Europe...}
microsoft.visualstudio          Registered        {account, account/project}                                                                             {North Central US, South Central US, East US, West US...}
```

Each ProviderNamespace Correspond to a big service, and you can use the following command for detail in a namespace:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.AppService
```

Note: this command will give you all resource type AppService provide.

Some services do not appear in this list. I am not sure why. For example:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.HDInsight
```

Microsoft.HDInsight is not in the list.

You can get more at [Get-AzureRmResourceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603615.aspx)

Comment: This was extremely informative, thank you!

I realized what the issue was, shortly after. I thought I had Azure Powershell installed on this machine, but that was not the case. Oddly enough, it let me get up to that command before it realized it wasn't installed.